# Prove that If $x$ is an accumulation point of $S$, then every neighborhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $S$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

To prove that every neighborhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $S$ whenever $x$ is an accumulation point of $S$, we will suppose to the contrary that there exists a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that

$$N \cap S = \{s_1, \cdots, s_n\}$$

Since $x$ is an accumulation point of $S$, then every deleted neighborhood $N^*_{\delta} \cap S \neq \varnothing$. We then select a particular $\delta = \min\{|x-s_i| \, : \, s_i \neq x\}$. Then $\delta > 0$, but we have

$$N^*_{\delta} \cap \, (N \cap S) = \varnothing$$

which is a contradiction, so every neighborhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $S$.

Are there any problems with this proof?

Comment: The claim is not true in general. For example in a finite space with indiscrete topolgy, every point is an accumulation point of ecevery nonempty subset. Does the use of $|\cdot|$ mean that the problem is specifically about $S\subseteq \Bbb R$?

Comment: yes, $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Looks good. You should point out that $N_{\delta}^* \cap S = \emptyset$ rather than $N_{\delta}^* \cap(N\cap S)$ though.

Comment: But is it clear that $N^*_{\delta} \cap S = \varnothing$?

Comment: @AlexG. I don't think we any information that $N^*_{\delta} \cap S = \varnothing$, since $S$ is an arbitrary subset of the reals. The only fact that we do have is that $N^*_{\delta} \cap (N\cap S)$ is empty by definition of $\delta$. Please correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can assume without loss of generality that $N = N_{\epsilon}$ for some small enough $\epsilon > 0$. Then clearly $\delta < \epsilon$ and so $N_\delta^* \cap(N \cap S) = N_\delta^* \cap S$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen sir, I think claim is true for general metric space? am i correct? Please reply.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen sir, what if topological space is infinite? Please reply...

Answer (score 1):

Let $B_\alpha$ be a neighborhood of $x$. That is:

$$ B_\alpha = \{z : |x - z| < \alpha\},$$

for $\alpha > 0$.

Take the sequence $$a_n = x + \frac{1}{n}.$$ This converges to $x$ as $n$ approaches to $+\infty$. This means that $x$ is accumulation point for some sets that contain $s$. Moreover:

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists m \in \mathbb{N} : n > m \Rightarrow a_n \in B_\varepsilon. $$

Now, consider the sets $S = B_\varepsilon$, $N = B_\alpha$ and $S \cap N$. It's clear that you can always find a $m'$ such that

$$n > m' \Rightarrow a_n \in S \cap N,$$

and the $a_n$'s with $n > m'$ are, of course, infinite.

Comment: Nice direct proof

Answer (score 0):

An alternative proof is the following that doesn't use contradiction.

Let $x$ be an accumulation point of $S$ 
Let $N$ be a neighbourhood of $x$.

We will construct a sequence $(x_n)$ of distinct points in $N\cap S$.

Let $\epsilon_1 >0 $ such that $B_{\epsilon_1} (x) \subset N$
This can be done since $N$ is a neighbourhood of $x$

Since $x$ is an accumulation point of $N$,
$\exists x_1 \in (B_{\epsilon_1}(x) \{x\}) \cap S$

Let $\epsilon_2 =\min \{ 1/2, d(x_1,x)\} >0$
As before, $\exists x_2 \in (B_{\epsilon_2}(x) \{x\}) \cap S$

Let $\epsilon_3 =\min \{ 1/3, d(x_2,x)\} >0$
Again, $\exists x_3 \in (B_{\epsilon_3}(x) \{x\}) \cap S$

And so on.

This way we have constructed a sequence of real numbers $(\epsilon_n)$ and $(x_n)$ in $S$ such that $0< \epsilon_{n+1} < \epsilon_n$
Thus $\forall n,m : n\neq m \Rightarrow x_n \neq x_m$ and $\forall n\geq 1, x_n \in B_{\epsilon_n} (x) \subset B_{\epsilon_1} \subset N$
This shows that $N\cap S$ contains infinitely many distinct points in $S$